# java.lang.ClassCastException: GridLayout.LayoutParams cannot cast to Frame.LayoutParams

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 with Android Studio 2.0

For didactic purpose I want to move as many `View` attributes as I can from XML to Java.

I've got an `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` inside a `GridLayout` and I want to move RecyclerView's `android:layout_gravity`.

From `GridLayout.setGravity` and `R.attr` documentation I know that `layout_gravity` is used by the child to set gravity attribute in the parent.

The following code is root cause of the exception:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams parentParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
parentParams.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
container.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
```

The XML I want to shrink:

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/alphabet_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!--android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">-->
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</GridLayout>
```

This is the exception chain:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.GridLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:431)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I looked up **android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)** to find this:

```
if (cacheIndex < 0 || sIgnoreMeasureCache) {
    // measure ourselves, this should set the measured dimension flag back
    onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    mPrivateFlags3 &= ~PFLAG3_MEASURE_NEEDED_BEFORE_LAYOUT;
} else {
```

I don't really get how it ended up calling `android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure instead of android.view.View.onMeasure`

What am I missing?

Comment: show what is the container there please -- container.setLayoutParams(parentParams);

Comment: @dione llorera container is a **GridLayout**

Comment: @MPG which import statement are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet you provide:

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams parentParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
parentParams.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
container.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
```

it *appears* from the variable name `container` that you are attempting to apply the `LayoutParams` you construct to your `GridLayout` instance, rather than to your `RecyclerView` instance. I'd expect the final line to look something more like

```
recyclerView.setLayoutParams(parentParams);
```

If my assumption is correct, the parent of your `GridLayout` will end up attempting to parse the `LayoutParams` you built. This parent is unlikely(!) to itself be a `GridLayout` (I'd guess from the stack trace that it's a `FrameLayout`), and is choking when it tries to deal with `GridLayout`-specific `LayoutParams`.

Comment: I AM applying LayoutParams to GridLayout because the layout_gravity is to be applied to the parent of the child.
However RecyclerView.LayoutParams does not contain any method related to gravity.

Comment: While the parent is expected to parse those layout parameters, you must still apply them to the child (which will pass that information to the parent when requested). Consider the XML you are attempting to reproduce in code; the `layout_gravity` attribute is set on the _child_, not on the parent! Try applying your `LayoutParams` to the `RecyclerView` (i.e. the child) in code as I suggested - it should work as you expect.

Comment: RecyclerView.LayoutParams doesn't contain any method related to gravity. Do you mean I got to cast **parentParams** from _GridLayout.LayoutParams_ to _RecyclerView.LayoutParams_

Comment: Nope, you should still be using a `GridLayout$LayoutParams` instance even though you're applying them to the `RecyclerView`. The `LayoutParams` type you use should match the parent `ViewGroup` type rather than the type of the child to which you are applying them. It's a weird API, that's for sure :)

Comment: Not only weird but also not properly documented.
Anyway your solution works fine.